Power BI Number format
I have a large data set provides business unit sales numbers. I have written dax that will format the numbers as the sales folks drill down on the data set. It will for from Billions to thousands. Here is the DAX:
Act - Plan = 
var CurrentValue = ABS( 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(DataBase[Value]),
    DataBase[Measure] = "Revenue (Projected)",
    DataBase[Period] = "CY Actual"
)+CALCULATE(
    SUM(DataBase[Value]),
    DataBase[Measure] = "Open Order $s",
    DataBase[Period] = "CY Actual"
)-CALCULATE(
    SUM(DataBase[Value]),
    DataBase[Measure] = "Revenue (Projected)",
    DataBase[Period] = "Baseforecast")
)
Return 
Switch (
    true (),
    CurrentValue <= 1E3, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0.00" ),
        CurrentValue <= 1E6, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0,.00 K" ),
        CurrentValue <= 1E9, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0,,.00 M"),
        FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0,,,.00 B")
    )
The issue that I am running in is that the formatted value will not show negative (1-2=1).
what should I include to be able to reflect the proper value? 

Thank you for your time!

I added these lines.. still no good
CurrentValue <= -1E3, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "-#,0.00" ),
CurrentValue <= -1E6, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "-#,0,.00 K" ),
CurrentValue <= -1E9, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "-#,0,,.00 M"),

You have ABS wrapped for CurrentValue and this is what you are outputting, so will always be positive.
Try this instead:
Act - Plan = 
  var CurrentValue = // ABS removed here
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(DataBase[Value]),
    DataBase[Measure] = "Revenue (Projected)",
    DataBase[Period] = "CY Actual"
  ) + CALCULATE(
    SUM(DataBase[Value]),
    DataBase[Measure] = "Open Order $s",
    DataBase[Period] = "CY Actual"
  ) - CALCULATE(
    SUM(DataBase[Value]),
    DataBase[Measure] = "Revenue (Projected)",
    DataBase[Period] = "Baseforecast")
  )
  var absValue = ABS(CurrentValue) // ABS done here for switch conditionals
  Return 
    Switch (
      true (),
      absValue <= 1E3, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0.00" ),
      absValue <= 1E6, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0,.00 K" ),
      absValue <= 1E9, FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0,,.00 M"),
      FORMAT ( CurrentValue, "#,0,,,.00 B")
    )

